# How to use a binding several times in the single Racket's match pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

I'm trying to match elements in the list, in the situation when I don't know their exact order.

This code works fine:

```
(match '((0 1 2) (3) (0 4) (5 6 7 8))
  ((list `(,a ,b ,_) _ ... `(,a ,_) _ ...) 
    b)
  (else #f)) 

; result: 1
```

But when I apply a `list-no-order` form in the pattern, I get an error:

```
(match '((0 1 2) (3) (0 4) (5 6 7 8))
  ((list-no-order `(,a ,_) `(,a ,b ,_) _ ...)
    b)
  (else #f))

; error: 
; a10: unbound identifier;
; also, no #%top syntax transformer is bound
; in: a10

; expected: 1
```

Unfortunately, in the [Racket reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) I don't see other options to implement this kind of matching.

Are there any solutions? I don't want to break matching into the stages, using several matches, I would like to keep pattern in a nice single form.

Comment: This will work for what you want: `((list-no-order (list a __) (list b c _) _ ...) c)`, output being `1`.

Comment: Right, but this pattern will also match '((0 1 2) (3) (100 4) (5 6 7 8)), while I want to match '(0 1 2) and '(0 4), i.e. lists with the same first element

Comment: You can add a `#:when` clause, ie. `((list-no-order (list a _) (list b c _) _ ...) #:when (equal? a b) c)`. This will only match the pattern if `a` and `b` have the same value.

Comment: Whether or not your specified program should succeed, that looks like a bug to me. You should file a bug report. I do wonder whether the racket7 transition will affect this though.

Comment: I submitted a bug report for you:

Comment: https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/1964

Comment: @assefamaru Nice! As a variant to keep pattern in a single form, thank you!

Comment: @JohnClements, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: match doesn't currently support this. HOWEVER, a pull request by Alex Knauth should now provide a vastly better error message. This is part of 
pull request #2000,

https://github.com/racket/racket/pull/2000

...which I would expect to appear in a [snapshot build](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/) in less than a week, and also in the next major release, which (spoiler alert!) I expect to be Racket v7.

Umm... also, @assefamaru should probably actually get credit for providing the best workaround; namely, adding a guard, as she or he mentions in the comment above.

Comment: I would be happy to make a credit to assefamaru, but how I make it? I have not enough points to upvote yet. Seems I have to ask a couple of more questions on stackoverflow

Comment: ...or HER! (sorry)